# In Visual Studio how do I force a build if a component is outdated?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, msbuild, build

Recently I put my two C++ projects under one solution in VS 2010.

One project creates a DLL and the second is a test app that makes use of the DLL.

Before this transition, I used to build the DLL and copy the output .dll file into the Debug directory of the test app, then I would build that too (The app loads the DLL at run-time with LoadLibrary())

I wonder if there is a way to force a build of the DLL project when I build the test app , **if the existing .dll file is outdated**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I  wonder if there is a way to force a build of the DLL project when I build the test app , if the existing .dll file is outdated.

Yes.

In solution explorer, right click on the exe project and select `Project Dependencies...`.
Select the DLL project checkbox and you're all set.

If your DLL project was a static library then this checkbox would also auto link to your dependency implicitly.

Comment: I guess this would work if the DLL project's output directory was in the PATH environment variable, so that the LoadLibrary() function could find it. In my case I need that the current .dll file (in the app's Debug directory) be compared to the last built .dll file that exists in the DLL project's output dir.

Comment: Simply set the output directory of the dll project and the exe project to the same place.